# Testing Library with React navigation not works as expected

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-testing-library, vitest

In my header there is cart icon. when user click on cart icon it takes to 'cart page'. I and testing the `cart icon` click event. But getting `null` from the `cart` page.

here is my test for header:

```
import { screen, waitFor } from "@testing-library/react";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { describe, expect, it } from "vitest";
import { renderWithProviders } from "./../../../utils/utils-for-tests";
import Header from "./Header";

describe("header component", () => {
  it("should redirect to cart page on click of cart button", async () => {
    await renderWithProviders(
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Header />
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
    const user = userEvent.setup();
    const cartIcon = screen.queryByText(/Cart/) as Element; //header component
    expect(cartIcon).toBeInTheDocument();
    await user.click(cartIcon);
    await waitFor(async () => {
      const cart = screen.queryByText(/Shopping Cart/i) as Element; //shopping cart page
      console.log("cart", cart); //null
    });
  });
});
```

Here is the sample [live demo](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/y4tv5h?file=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FHeader%2FHeader.spec.tsx&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsgwpzka000a3b6lmja78gyx%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B60.46454767726161%252C39.53545232273839%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsgwpzka00033b6l5wcfzwg2%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsgwpzka00073b6lal1x0d8w%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsgwpzka00093b6l76c4tblt%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B64.28434584363086%252C35.71565415636914%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clsgwpzka00033b6l5wcfzwg2%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsgwpzk900023b6l39mxnvhj%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Fcomponents%252FHeader%252FHeader.spec.tsx%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsgwpzka00033b6l5wcfzwg2%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clsgwpzk900023b6l39mxnvhj%2522%257D%252C%2522clsgwpzka00093b6l76c4tblt%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsgwpzka00083b6l6lf9ljix%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A5173%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252Fproducts%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsgwpzka00093b6l76c4tblt%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clsgwpzka00083b6l6lf9ljix%2522%257D%252C%2522clsgwpzka00073b6lal1x0d8w%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsgwpzka00073b6lal1x0d8w%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsgwpzka00043b6lm4m3vkaw%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsgwpzka00053b6lil6l4evx%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TERMINAL%2522%252C%2522shellId%2522%253A%2522clscvz92c000zdjgu62zgg5qn%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsgwpzka00063b6l56iznxv6%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TERMINAL%2522%252C%2522shellId%2522%253A%2522clseui32s002ldjgud8q2gmx1%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clsgwpzka00053b6lil6l4evx%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

Comment: The sandbox link is not working.

Comment: @Nymeria - can you check now? you can access now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated my code in to follows. it works fine.

```
import { describe, it, expect, beforeAll } from "vitest";
import { screen, render } from "@testing-library/react";
import { user } from "@testing-library/user-event";
import Header from "./Header";
import user from "@testing-library/user-event";
import { MemoryRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { Products } from "../Products/Products";

describe("Header component testings", () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    render(
      <MemoryRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Header />} />
          <Route path="/products" element={<Products />} />
        </Routes>
      </MemoryRouter>,
    );
  });

  it("should render header component", async () => {
    const h1 = await screen.queryByText("Welcome to app");
    expect(h1).toBeInTheDocument();
  });

  it("should render header component", async () => {
    user.click(screen.getByRole("link", { name: "Go to products" }));
    expect(await screen.findByText("Products page")).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```